# creating a script which finds two alternating patterns

Tags: shell, grep, wireshark

So my issue is that I need to make a script which finds a pattern where Time to live and User-Agent occur in that order and I increment a count (or grab what data I want, etc; it will likely evolve from there.)

For example:

```
Time to live: 64
Some other data: ________
...
User-Agent: Mozilla/Chrome/IE:Windows/Unix/Mac
```

So basically the data appears in that order TTL then user-agent, from that information I can grab the data I want but I don't know what to do about the pattern to identify this. If it helps I'm getting this data from a Wireshark capture saved as a text file.

Thanks to Shellter I got to the point where I have:

```
egrep '    User-Agent:|    Time to live:' ../*.txt
```

which finds if both (TTL and UA) are in the file.

I'd appreciate any assistance.

```
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 128
    Protocol: TCP (6)
    Header checksum: 0x7e4d [correct]
        [Good: True]
        [Bad: False]
    Source: 1.1.1.3 (1.1.1.3)
    Destination: 1.1.1.4 (1.1.1.4)

//packet 2      
    Fragment offset: 0
    Time to live: 128
    Protocol: TCP (6)
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Message: GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Method: GET
        Request URI: /
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
    Host: mail.yahoo.com\r\n
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.7.5) Gecko/20041107 Firefox/1.0\r\n
    Accept: text/xml,application/xml,application/xhtml+xml,text/html;q=0.9,text/plain;q=0.8,image/png,*/*;q=0.5\r\n
```

I apologize for the slow reply, I had to do some editing.

So basically I just need to identify when a TTL only occurs, when a TTL occurs and there's user-agent data; basically I use this to identify clients behind a gateway.

So if TTL is 126 (windows) and I see 125, we assume it's behind a gateway and count++.
If we get that same count but with a different user-agent but same OS, count doesn't change.
If we get that same count but with a different user-agent and OS, count++.

so output could be as simple as:

```
1 (ttl)
1 (ttl+os)
2 (ttl+os+ua)
```

from the example (not the data) above.

Comment: please edit your question to include 2 sets of data, simplified sample data as you have but including sample data that should be ignored. AND include your required output from that data. Continue to use the `{}` formatting tool. Good luck.

Comment: There we go, data up.

Comment: Do we really need **all** of that data to understand your problem? Please consider editing down to a minimal amount noise data that should ignored. Hopefully your problem is not too complex, and can be illustarted with 20 lines or less of sample data. Good luck.

Comment: There we are, I hope that's a little better.

Comment: So the thing to note is there are 2 TTL and 1 user-agent data, the rest is noise data.

Comment: ok, thats good. thanks for your effort in clarifying. Back in a while.

Comment: I think I'm done editing my answer ;-). I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still a little unclear what you're looking to report, but maybe this will help.

We're going to use `awk` as that tool was designed to solve problems of this nature (among many others).

And while my output doesn't match your output exactly, I think the code is self-documenting enough that you can work with this, and make a closer approximation to your final need. Feel free to update your question with your new code, new output, and preferably an exact example of the output you hope to achieve.

```
awk '
        /Time to live/{ttl++}
        /User-Agent/{agent++}
        /Windows|Linux|Solaris/{os++}
        END{print "ttl="ttl; print "os="os; print"agent="agent}
'  ttlTest.txt
```

**output**

```
ttl=2
os=1
agent=1
```

The key thing to understand is that awk (and most Unix based reg-ex utilities, grep included) read each line of input and decide if it will print (or do something else) with the current line of data.

`awk` normally will print every line of input if you give it something like

```
awk '{print $1}' file
```

i this example, printing just the first field from each line of data.

In the solution above, we're filtering the data with regular expressions and the applying an `action` because we have matched some data, i.e.

```
    /Time to live/{  ttl++ }
    |             |  |     |
    |             |  |     > block end
    |             |  > action (in this case, increment value of ttl var
    |             > block begin
    >/ regex to match / #
```

So we have 2 other 'regular expressions' that we're scanning each line for, and every time we match that regular expression, we increment the related variable.

Finally, `awk` allows for `END` blocks that execute after all data has been read from files.
This is how we create your summary report. `awk` also has `BEGIN` blocks that execute before any data has been read.

Another idiom of awk scanning that allows for more complex patterns to be match looks like

```
awk '{
      if (   /Time to live/ && User-Agent/ ) {
         ttl_agent++
      }
     }' ttlTest.txt
```

Where the first and last `{ }` block-definition characters, indicate that this logic will be applied to each line that is read from the data. This block can be quite complex, and can use other variable values to be evaluated inside the `if` test, like `if ( var=5 ) { print "found var=5"}`.

IHTH

Comment: That is perfect, Shellter you are awesome! Thank you once again for the help.

Comment: glad that helped. Thinking to the future, you might want to capture this sort of data in a statistics file. You can put the data all on one line with `printf("%s\t%s\%s\n", ttl, os, agent)`. Good luck.

Comment: I actually got a really strange bug after iterating through a dataset (ttl= windows=317 linux=1 solaris= agent=340) so no ttl (it's quite possible there would be no solaris), does this occur when a dataset is too large or is there a way to remedy this?

Comment: I routinely process files in the GB range. Shouldn't be any limit, as  unix utilities aren't limited on filesize because they read one line at at time (Maybe a monster line is throwing you, but unlikely). If you were storing the complete file in memory, that might cause a problem, but you would get an error msg 'out of memory'. Almost certainly, either your `ttl` variable is misspelled either where you set it or print it, OR, you have code that is resetting the value of `ttl` to zero just before you print it out. Feel free to post a new q, with exact output.

Comment: It's ossible a binary char is throwing things off, but low probability. Does it fail regardless of what file you use for input, or just 1 specific file? Good luck.

Comment: Well, the file I tried is 2.2GB large pcap file, so the count may be ridiculously large. I didn't have issues with some of the other flows I tried.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm being a dummy, too much work not enough sleep. pcap to textfile first.

Comment: There you go! Get some sleep! Learn to set expecations for your boss! ;-) Hmmm ... that will take, .... oh gosh ..... hm, I don't know, if we're lucky, about 6 weeks? ... ? ... Good luck.